# Why Choose Dialogflow Messenger Despite Its Limitations?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, messenger, dialogflow-cx

Been pondering a bit on Dialogflow Messenger. It's still in beta, support and compatibility might be hit or miss, and it's specifically mentioned that it's designed for public data only. Plus, it allows unauthenticated individuals to query the agent.

Despite all these limitations, I've seen some enterprises go for it. Just trying to understand the rationale behind choosing it for serious deployments. Anyone have insights?

Cheers.

As Botcopy | Google Cloud Partners CMO I've been exploring various chatbot tools and came across Dialogflow Messenger. I haven't actually used it yet myself, but in going through the documentation, some things jumped out at me:

It's still in beta.

The data provided by the agent should be public.

Any unauthenticated individual can query the agent.

With these factors in mind, I was surprised to see some companies using it for enterprise deployments.

Answer (score 1):

One of the probable reasons why enterprises are using Dialogflow Messenger even if it is still in Beta phase is those enterprises must have been using Google Cloud Platform services already. Dialogflow Messenger is a basic front-end tool which allows an end-user to interact with a Dialogflow agent, and having a conversational chatbot must have been one of the features they needed. Also, their requirements might not be too complex that is why they opted to use Dialogflow Messenger to create a very basic chatbot.
Dialogflow Messenger is a better option if you want some services other than using agent in built-in console in GCP, also, when used as an additional service, it is free of charge.

Comment: Makes sense. But I think it’s meant to be just a test widget during design phase or for hobbyists or small use cases. Not ADA accessible or supported and doesn’t seem compliant, safe or even legal for an enterprise giant business that probably wouldn’t care that it’s free.

Comment: Regarding "The data provided by the agent should be public." , how about if we authenticate user by asking his id details (like date of birth, last name, last 4 digit of SSN [for US users]) and then give the data. Is it still considered public information? can someone get those details by other means? DialogFlow support is very poor and doesn't answer much of the questions.